# How do i fix this server error in backup buddy?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to upload a backup with backupbuddy, I keep getting this error on the database step, Unable to connect / authenticate to MySQL server. Unable to connect to database server and/or select the database. Details: ``. I am sure my database settings are correct.

I've already tried making new databases, using the setup wizard, no avail.

Comment: If the server is not local, port 3306 is usually blocked by the firewall , in the default settings also you can only access from local host. can you elaborate which settings you are using i am guessing a remote server, which will ot work as explained before

Comment: yes, im using a server from hostgator to host my website.